# How can I use `asset://` for non-APK file(s) on Android in a mapbox-gl Style?

Tags: android, react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I've been using [Mapbox GL Native](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native) (specifically [react-native-mapbox-gl](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl)).  I'm generating my own vector tiles on a server, and I'd like to have the user download them onto their device from the mobile app.  Then I want Mapbox GL to use the local tiles, specified via a TileJSON file referenced in the Mapbox GL Style file.

I've got it working on iOS (at least in the simulator).  My `style.json` looks like the following:

```
{
    "version":8,
    "name":"Bright",
    "sources":{
        "mapbox":{
            "type":"vector",
            "url": "asset:///absolute/path/map/tile.json"
        }
    },
    "sprite":"asset:///absolute/path/map/sprites/mysprite",
    "glyphs":"asset:///absolute/path/map/glyphs/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf",
    "metadata":{...},
    "layers":[...]
}
```

with the `tile.json` looking like:

```
{
    "tiles":[
        "asset:///absolute/path/map/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"
    ],
    "tilejson":"2.0.0",
    // plus lots of other stuff
}
```

On Android this doesn't work. It appears that `asset://` only works on files bundled inside the APK, not on the filesystem.

Is there something I can do on the Android platform to let Mapbox GL load my downloaded tiles from off the device?

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to make the same thing work, can you maybe post a gist of your entire configuration, mine is not working

Comment: @ospfranco I ended up not implementing the feature. It SHOULD have been added from this pull request: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/pull/6497

That said, I haven't tried implementing it myself yet.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the file:/// path? This usually loads from your app's file directory, eg.

```
"file:///absolute/path/map/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"
```

Comment: Yup!  The `file:///` scheme was actually implemented after I created this question.  See the issue at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/6273. Given this is now the correct way to do this, I'll mark this answer as correct :)

Comment: @EricPalakovichCarr Yes, I happened to stumble upon that git thread a little after as well. Great work on getting that implemented. Been a bit of a white whale for me!

Comment: Yeah, ditto for me :)